# Google embed api set chart background color

Tags: charts, google-api, google-visualization

i am trying to edit the background colour of my chart however it isnt working i can only edit the background colour of the full thing not the chart area, my code is below

```
var sessions = {
        query: {
            dimensions: 'ga:date',
            metrics: 'ga:sessions'
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'LINE',
            options: {
                width: '100%',
                title: 'Sessions',
                titleTextStyle: {
                    color: '#0f55c4',
                    fontSize: '16',
                    bold: true
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I have tried all the following combinations none have worked;

```
backgroundColor: 'red', (changed background colour not chart colour)

chartArea: {
        backgroundColor:'red'
    } (again background colour only)

chartArea: {
    backgroundColor: {
        fill: 'red'
    }
} (again background colour only)

chartArea: {
    fill: 'red'
} (doesn't work)
```

Not to sure what else i can try I've tried everything i can find in the documentation and several sites nothing seams to work it just goes onto the whole background not just the chart area, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options) you're able to change the background color and the backgroundcolor of the chartArea.

I'm able to change both of these colors with the following option:

```
    var options = {
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    chartArea: {
        backgroundColor:'#e5e5e5'
    }
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/6nsg9hsj/2/).

Sadly I'm not familiar with the way you have arranged your options and such, but my guess would be that you should place this option within

```
 options: {
                width: '100%',
.....
                chartArea: {
                     backgroundColor:'#e5e5e5'
                }
.......
};
```

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: Hey,

Yes that works for me as well however if you go to this image: http://imgur.com/oRYbIgh i want the blue bit to basically be a different colour but i cant seam to find this anywhere, at first i thought that the blue bit was the chart area (know its not the case now).

Thanks for the help.